I'm looking for a certain animated series (no not anime)
It starts out with a young boy and his father in a mobile home in a desert canyon. The boy wanders off, I don't remember why, but finds a glove nearby. The boy puts it on, finding out he can't take it off. He goes back to his father. His father knows what it is, but the boys does not. Later in the series, it starts to evolve more around combat and chi related training. Skipping to a point in the series where the boy finds a training facility he needed to defeat a person in combat, although I can't remember it all that well. I'm pretty sure it was aired on TV at one point and time, but I also saw it on Netflix a few years back. I can't remember the name, can you please help?

was it an older series or newer? Was it in english? Do you think it originated in another country? What was the glove for? Can you describe any of the characters?

I think this might be The Mummy: The Animated Series (2001-03), based on the The Mummy and The Mummy Returns (the ones with Brendan Fraser).


It starts out with a young boy and his father in a mobile home in a desert canyon.

I can't remember whether they drove around in a mobile home or not, but they do travel all over the world and spend a lot of time in deserts.

The boy wanders off, I don't remember why, but finds a glove nearby. The boy puts it on, finding out he can't take it off. He goes back to his father. His father knows what it is, but the boy does not.

It's not a 'glove', but the Manacle of Osiris. Alex (the boy) is indeed unable to remove it: only the Lost Scrolls of Thebes can remove it. His father Rick (Fraser's character from the films) would know about the Manacle as he's a famous archaeologist.

Later in the series, it starts to evolve more around combat and chi related training.

The second season, subtitled Secrets of the Medjai, sees Alex being trained by the Medjai warrior clan, and was indeed more combat-oriented than the first.

The boy finds a training facility he needed to defeat a person in combat

That 'person' would probably have been Imhotep, the primary villain of the series and of the Mummy franchise as a whole.

Here's the first episode on YouTube:




Could it be Wish Kid (1991)


"WishKid" was a Saturday morning animated series created to play off
  the success of pre-teen movie star Macaulay Culkin (of Home Alone).
  Nick McClary owned a magic baseball glove which, if punched three
  times, granted his every wish. Stories--which were introduced in live
  action by Culkin--revolved around Nick's wishes and the trouble that
  usually followed. Nick's best friend was Darryl, the only one in on
  the glove's secrets and usually became involved in the adventures.
  Nick was frequently harassed by Frankie Dutweiler, the neighborhood
  bully; other characters included neighbor Mrs. Opal, Nick's mom and
  dad and his baby sister, Katie (voiced by Macaulay's kid sister,
  Quinn. The show ran one year on NBC, with new episodes airing on the
  Family Channel in 1996 (along with the original 13 NBC episodes).

The salient point being the magic glove of course. I wouldn't know if any of the episodes involved a fight, but the Wikipedia does mention an antagonist he must deal with.
It's also worth mentioning that: "Each story — introduced in a live-action prologue by Culkin — revolved around Nick's wishes and the trouble that always seemed to follow. It was up to Nick and others involved to resolve the situation and make things right."
